# Any f.p. faithful simple module over a primitive group ring?

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, modules, noncommutative-algebra, group-rings

Recall that a ring $R$ is **primitive** if it has a faithful simple left module. Let $G$ be a countable discrete group and $R=\mathbb{k}G$, where $\mathbb{k}$ denotes some field or $\mathbb{Z}$.

There are many work studying whether the group ring $R$ is primitive, see e.g. chapter 7 in D. Passman's book ``The algebraic structure of group rings."

For example, by a result of Formanek, if $\mathbb{k}$ is any field, and $G=F_2$, the non-abelian free group on two generators, then $\mathbb{k}G$ is primitive.

Clearly, a simple module is finitely generated, here is the question:

Is there a faithful simple left module over $\mathbb{k}F_2$ which is finitely presented?

---

I am also interested in $\mathbb{k}=\mathbb{Z}$ and other groups with primitive group rings.

Comment: If you replace the free group by the free monoid the answer is negative. The free monoid on 2-generators also has a primitive monoid ring by the same paper of Formanek but Lewin showed that every finitely presented module for a free algebra has a cofinite dimensional free submodule. Thus a finitely presented simple module would be finite dimensional and hence not faithful.  I don’t know if an analogue of Lewin’s result is true for free groups.

Comment: I see, I found this paper: Ideals of finite codimension in free algebras and the fc-localization. by Amnon Rosenmann and Shmuel Rosset. In theorem (4.3), they showed that at least for right ideals $I$ of $R:=$ the free group ring, in other words, for $M=R/I$, it still has Lewin's property as mentioned above. So I guess the answer may be No for free group ring.

Comment: It seems that way